# pyqt5 is running slow

Tags: python, pyqt5

So my program is a Sudoku and so far, I have finished the code that generates boards. I am trying to take this an implement it into pyqt5. I have done this through by making a button  correspond to each number in Sudoku board (so 81 buttons). I have a pc that is capable of running triple A games at high frame rates(if that matters). What could be the issue? I have put my code below.

```
import random
import numpy as np

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


# populates a row in random spaces
def populate():
    row = [0] * 9
    num_in_box = random.randint(3, 6)
    while True:
        spot = random.randint(0, 8)
        r = random.randint(1, 9)
        if r not in row:
            row[spot] = r
        if row.count(0) == (9 - num_in_box):
            break
    return row


# populates a grid in random spaces - has duplicates in column, row and box
mapped = list()
for x in range(9): mapped.append(populate())


# checks every number in column and row and returns numbers in list
def col_row_nums(array, row, col):
    check_col = [j for j in array[:, col] if j != 0]
    check_row = [i for i in array[row] if i != 0]
    if array[row][col] in check_col:
        check_col.remove(array[row][col])
    return check_col + check_row


# checks every number box and returns numbers in list
def box_nums(array, box_row):
    reshaped_box = np.reshape(array, (27, 3))
    list_boxes_in_rows = list()
    for a in range(3):
        for b in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                p2 = list(np.reshape((reshaped_box[c::3]), (3, 9)))
                for d in range(3): list_boxes_in_rows.append(p2[a])
    array_boxes_in_rows = np.array(list_boxes_in_rows)
    return [k for k in array_boxes_in_rows[box_row] if k != 0]


# Basically goes through each number and removes any duplicates so each column, row and box all have only one set of numbers 1 - 9
def finalize_board():
    box_rows_num = -1
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            box_rows_num += 1
            arr = np.array(mapped)
            possible_nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            col_row_duplicates = list()
            box_duplicates = list()
            used_nums = set(col_row_nums(arr, x, y)) | set(box_nums(arr, box_rows_num))

            for w in used_nums:
                col_row_count = col_row_nums(arr, x, y).count(w)
                box_count = box_nums(arr, box_rows_num).count(w)
                if col_row_count > 1: col_row_duplicates.append(w)
                if box_count > 1: box_duplicates.append(w)
            if mapped[x][y] in col_row_duplicates or mapped[x][y] in box_duplicates:
                remaining_nums = list(set(possible_nums) - set(used_nums))
                if len(remaining_nums) > 0: mapped[x][y] = random.choice(remaining_nums)
    return mapped


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        all_buttons = list()
        layout = qtw.QGridLayout()

        for x in range(9):
            for y in range(9):
                if finalize_board()[x][y] == 0: finalize_board()[x][y] = ' '
                all_buttons.append(layout.addWidget(qtw.QPushButton(str(finalize_board()[x][y])), x, y))

        self.setLayout(layout)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are executing the finalize_board function for each button, so if the function takes T seconds and you have N buttons (in your case 81), also in each iteration you are using K times that function (in your case 3), then the total time is T * N * K.

The solution is to invoke finalize_board only once.

```py
class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        all_buttons = list()
        layout = qtw.QGridLayout(self)

        board = finalize_board()

        for x, rows in enumerate(board):
            for y, cell in enumerate(rows):
                button = qtw.QPushButton(str(cell))
                layout.addWidget(button, x, y)
                all_buttons.append(button)
        self.show()
```